# Couldnot format namenode during hadoop installation in windows using cygwin

Tags: hadoop, cygwin, hdfs

I am installing Hadoop 0.19.1  in windows using Cygwin. When formating the namenode, i get the below error..

```
: No such file or directory
./hadoop: line 43: $'\r': command not found 
: No such file or directorycot/hadoop-0.19.1/bin 
./hadoop: line 45: $'\r': command not found 
./hadoop: line 47: syntax error near unexpected token `$'in\r'' 
'/hadoop: line 47: `case "`uname`" in..."
```

Please do tell me a solution!

Comment: What command are you using?

Comment: I used the follwing command..
bin/hadoop namenode -format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go through the below link and setup hadoop environment

http://cs.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Hadoop_Tutorial_1_--_Running_WordCount#Basic_Hadoop_Admin_Commands.